# Excitations & Pentagon axiom in algebraic theory for anyons

Tags: topological-field-theory, topological-order, topological-phase, anyons

I have been reading the anyon theory by [Kitaev](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0506438) and [Wang](https://web.math.ucsb.edu/%7Ezhenghwa/data/course/cbms.pdf). I have two possibly related questions:

1. Why is the Pentagon equation/axiom sufficient for characterizing associative relations?
2. Are there anyon theories with more than two elementary (non-composite) excitations?

Thanks for the excellent comments by user @AccidentalFourierTransform! My first question may be formulated in this way:

1. Are there physical reasons that enforce the Pentagon axiom? Why do we not consider axioms with more than four labels/excitations? (for example, [in the string-net theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0404617), the associative relation of interest is constructed to be a "tensor product" of four "spaces"; what could be the anyon analog of this special requirement?)

My impression has been that there is no anyon theory with more than two non-composite elementary excitations. This seems to be the reason that the Pentagon equation (together with braiding structures, of course) is sufficient in describing anyons. Is this naive intuition correct? Could someone enlighten me on this subject?

---

cross-posted on [physics overflow](https://physicsoverflow.org/44072) (no answers so far).

Comment: (1) is a non-trivial theorem in the theory of tensor categories (IIRC, one of MacLane's coherence theorems). It is a pure math result, I'm sure it is discussed at length in any text on the subject. (2) what do you mean, exactly? is an excitation just a simple object (an anyon)? If so, $\mathfrak{su}(2)_k$ has $k+1$ such objects, so it does indeed contain more than two anyons (for $k>1$). In fact, there are only two fusion categories of rank 2 (up to some notion of equivalence), namely the so-called semion and Fibonacci. So *most* theories have more than two elementary excitations.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, thank you for your comment! (1) in the mathematics context, the Pentagon axiom is taken for granted. My question, in this regard, would be why is the Pentagon axiom so important? What are some of the "nice" properties that can be related to physical processes? (2) by non-compsite elementary excitations I mean excitations that cannot be a fusion product of others (except for the trivial vacuum "particle").

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, On the Pentagon axiom: my question may also be understood as: why do we not consider axioms with more than four tensor products?

Comment: Its another "theorem" that higher tensor products can be rewritten in terms of smaller ones and that the coherence theorems up to $n=4$ suffice.

Comment: @NDewolf, which theorem is that? Do you remember? Why is the word "theorem" in quotation? Is it some conjecture?

Comment: The quotation marks are not really necessary. But intuitively (as for ordinary algebra) its clear that once you have an associator you can permute brackets with any number of factors. As for a name, it's all part of MacLane's coherence theorem as mentioned by AccidentalFourierTransform. Note that higher coherence conditions would indeed arise if one were to go to higher categories (the pentagonator for monoidal bicategories replaces the pentagon condition and is relevant for higher TFTs)

Comment: @NDewolf, I see! This is very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, in a sense, what I mean by non-composite excitations may be understood as (the terminology here is only speculative) generators of fusion algebra.

Comment: sure. Again: there is only two fusion categories with two generators. All other categories have three or more generators.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, I see! Thanks!